# Вылетает телеграмм бот

Tags: python, telegram, бот

в телеграмм боте периодически получаю HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=25). Как обойти?

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь proxy, возможно из-за того, что с российского ip